# What happens when an onCreate event happens again while another Firebase function is already running?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

## Background

I have a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) which sometimes can take a while to complete (20-60 seconds).

It [gets triggered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) by a write to Firebase, which means that it starts processing at the [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-create) event.

## Problem

I have been doing some scripted testing by creating a new record in Firebase every N seconds, but it seems that if N is less than 20 seconds, the next onCreate trigger just doesn't fire.

In other words I end up in a situation like this:

Firebase:

1. record1
2. record2
3. record3
4. record4

Results written by the triggered function to another node in Firebase:

1. result-from-record1

...
record2, record3, record4 does not seem to trigger the function again.

## Homework

I have re-checked Firebase documentation, but I cannot seem to find any information that explains this case.

[There is some information about quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) for connected users, but it's only about connected users, not about the same triggers firing many times before the previously triggered function completes.

## Questions

What is the default behavior of Firebase triggered functions in case it gets triggered while the previously triggered function is still running?

Is there any way to maybe cancel the running function if it gets triggered by a new onWrite?

Is there any queue of those triggered and running functions? ([this queue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-queue) doesn't seem to be the one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the default behavior of Firebase triggered functions in case it gets triggered while the previously triggered function is still running?

There is no guarantee about how functions are invoked - they could happen in sequence on a single server instance, or they could run in run in parallel on multiple server instances.  The order of invocation of functions is also not guaranteed.

> Is there any way to maybe cancel the running function if it gets triggered by a new onWrite?

No.

> Is there any queue of those triggered and running functions? (this queue doesn't seem to be the one)

There is no visible queue.  Internally, Cloud Functions is using pubsub to manage the stream of events emitted by the database, but this is an implementation detail, and you have no direct control over how it works.

As for why your function doesn't seem to execute when you expect - there's not enough detail in your question to make a guess.  Without seeing actual code, as well as the specific steps to take to reproduce the issue, it's not possible to say.

You might want to watch my [video series on how Cloud Functions works](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM) in order to better understand its behavior.

Comment: Doug, thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! May I ask if you know if there is a way to disallow the same function to be invoked again if its instances are running at the moment? Turns out I don't need any parallel execution, but I have some legacy Firebase (TypeScript) code to run :) Maybe I could just set 'Maximum functions instances' in GCP settings to 1?

Comment: That setting does not give a hard guarantee for serial execution.  If you read over the documentation for it, you will see that there are circumstances where the number of instances can go greater than your configuration (such as a burst in traffic).  If you need pure serial execution, you should route all your invocations through a Cloud Tasks queue that's configured to only allow tasks to execute 1 at a time in parallel.  The task can be configured to run an HTTP Cloud Function.  https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/

Comment: In particular: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate